# JS Validation if dropdown value selected or not

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to write a validation block inside my JS to check if the user has selected a value or not and pop up a message if the value is not selected.

```
function validate(form) {
    var success = true;
    var message = "";

    if (form.dropdown.selectedIndex ==  0 )  {  
        form.save.disabled=true;

        if (0 < message.length) {
            message += "\n"; 
        }
        message += "dropdown  value should be selected.";
    }

    if (0 < message.length) {
        alert(message);
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}
```

When I click on Save button I call this function. I don't see errors in the logs. 
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrongly here? Or can you guide me what is the correct method to validate if the user has selected a value before allowing to save?

Thanks!

Comment: @smiley—don't use tabs for indenting, it messes with SO's formatting.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It would make this easier.

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jd5Ka/.  It must be somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no option is selected, the select element's [selectedIndex](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-85676760) will be `-1`. It's recommended that one option is always set to *selected*, that way you know what the default selected option is (user agents may make the first option selected by default if you don't).

So the test:

```
if (form.dropdown.selectedIndex ==  0 )  {
```

will only be true if the first option has the selected attribute. So either test against -1 or make the first option selected by default, e.g.

```
<select name="dropdown" ...>
  <option selected value="default">Please select an option
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: THis is how i am populating the list .... <%
con= DataObjectConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
dPreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(X.OWNER)) AS OWNER FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(OWNER)) AS OWNER  FROM MGD_CONTENT  WHERE OWNER IS NOT NULL AND 0 < LENGTH(RTRIM(LTRIM(OWNER)))) X ORDER BY LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(X.OWNER))) ");
dResultSet = dPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (dResultSet != null && dResultSet.next()) {    String owner = dResultSet.getString("OWNER");
 if (ownerArray == null) {    ownerArray = new ArrayList(); }    ownerArray.add(owner);
%>

Comment: <tr>
  <td valign="middle" align="right" width="135"><label for="dropdown">User id:<span class="font_red"><strong>*</strong></span></label></td>
   <td><img src="common/images/shim.gif" border="0" height="1" width="10" alt=""/> 
   <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
   <option value="">Select Your User ID</option>
  <%
  for (int b = 0; ownerArray != null && b < ownerArray.size(); b++) {
   String ownerx = (String) ownerArray.get(b);
  %>
   <option value="<%=ownerx%>"><%=ownerx%></option>
 <%
  }
 %>
</select> </td>
  <td valign="middle" align="left"></td>
</tr>