# Magento - Change 0.00 in product view page to "some text"

Tags: magento, e-commerce

How do I go about changing  S0.00 in product veiw to some text of my choosing. On my site prices are generated once they select from a drop down menu inside the product view page. However I would like it to say something to the effect of, "please choose a option" instead of S0.00. Ive already removed the 0.00 from the list view. I want to now, change it so once they are in the product page it doesnt show 0.00 rather "please select an option" or something to that effect.

Im in /app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

but do not know what code to use or change.

Comment: im using simple products if that helps or is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to detect if user has selected a value or not. If not, display your text message. This should help: [JS Validation if dropdown value selected or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521983/js-validation-if-dropdown-value-selected-or-not)